# Can't add a section in FASM Syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, segment, fasm

I have some problem here with adding a section using FASM Syntax. I have checked on others websites and I am sure this is the right syntax. I must be missing something :

```
format elf executable 3
entry start

section '.text' readable executable

start:
mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

and FASM is giving me :

> flat assembler  version 1.70.03  (16384 kilobytes memory) 
>   exit.asm[4]: section '.text' readable executable error: illegal instruction.

Btw I can't also create a named segment like:

```
segment .data
```

but I can do :

```
segment readable executable
```

I can't find an explanation for this.

Answer (score 2):

The `section` keyword is to be used only if the result ELF will be later linked with external linkers.

If the `format` directive contains `executable` clause, only `segment` directives are allowed and the result file can be directly executed without linking.

This all is explained at the end of the related section in the [FASM manual ch.2.4.4](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4.4).

Comment: `If the format directive contains executable clause, only segment directives are allowed` -- what is this stated?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the [FASM documentation for ELFs](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4.4) aren't up to date. You should go to the [FASM forums](http://board.flatassembler.net/forum.php?f=4) and report and/or ask about it.

I got this to compile in `1.70.03`, adapted from the `elfexe` example:

```
format elf executable 3
entry start

segment readable executable

start:
mov     ebx,0
mov     eax,1
int     0x80
```

Comment: what's the number 3 in `executable 3`?

Comment: I think 3 is for Linux.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: It's probably the OS ABI identifier: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/gabi4+/ch4.eheader.html#osabi